# Target old version of action's dependency

Tags: github-actions

I have the following code that recently broke due to changes in [`@octokit/action`](https://github.com/octokit/action.js/):

```yaml
- name: Send Trigger to Parent Repository
  uses: actions/github-script@v6.3.3
  with:
    script: |
      const { Octokit } = require("@octokit/action");
      const octokit = new Octokit
      ({
        auth: '${{ env.GITHUB_TOKEN }}'
      })
      await octokit.rest.repos.createDispatchEvent
      ({
        owner: '${{ github.repository_owner }}',
        repo: '${{ matrix.parent_repo_name }}',
        event_type: '${{ env.EVENT_TYPE }}',
        client_payload: {
          submodule_name: '${{ github.event.repository.name }}',
          commit_message: `${{ github.event.head_commit.message }}`
        }
      });
```

The easiest solution I can think of is to target an older version of the action.

For example, I am able to target `v6.3.3` of [`actions/github-script`](https://github.com/actions/github-script) like so: `uses: actions/github-script@v6.3.3`.

But since `@octokit/action` is used within the script, I don't know how to target a specific version for it.

I have tried `require("@octokit/action@v6.0.6")`, but that did not work.

Is there a way to target the older version of the action from within the script?

Comment: Why were you importing that at all, rather than using the arguments the function's already called with (or even just the `gh` CLI, preinstalled on the hosted runners)? As far as I can tell, neither the current version (7.0.1) nor the one you're targeting (6.3.3) actually includes `@octokit/action` in its dependency tree, so I'm not sure where that's coming from.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I am stupid, I missed the line before is where it was actually being installed...

I had:

```yaml
- name: Install Octokit
  run: npm install @octokit/action
```

I changed it to:

```yaml
- name: Install Octokit
  run: npm install @octokit/action@v6.0.0
```